# Find leap years assignment

Tags: python

A garbage value is being sent to the function instead of the actual parameter. What's the problem with my code?

```
def find_leap_years(given_year):
    i=0
    count=0
    while(count<15):
        print(given_year)
        if(given_year%4==0)and(given_year%400==0):
            if(given_year%100!=0):
                list_of_leap_years[i]=given_year
                i+=1
                count+=1
        given_year+=1

    return list_of_leap_years

list_of_leap_years=find_leap_years(2000)
print(list_of_leap_years)
```

Comment: What output are you expecting? What are you actually getting? You need to supply some context.

Comment: As @Carcigenicate we need all of that, what function is beeing called with the wrong data? How did you get to that conclusion?

Comment: @Carcigenicate I'm trying to generate the next 15 leap years starting from the "given_year". However, "given_year" starts off with a random value instead of the value "2000" that is being passed.

Comment: @JazirAhammed With the code you posted it will print the argument that's passed in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of overlapping errors here, and the one is making the other harder to find.

1. The leap-year test has an error in it. It should be `if given_year % 4 == 0: if given_year % 100 != 0 or given_year % 400 == 0:`. That is, a year is a leap year if it is divisible by 4; but not if it is divisible by 100, unless it is also divisible by 400. The result of this error is that your original `if`-test is only `True` every 400th year and so the loop will run until it has tested 6,000 years. I suspect you were interrupting the program before this happened, so you didn't see the problem inside the `if`-test.
2. This won't work: `list_of_leap_years[i] = given_year`. If your code had ever reached that point you would have got the error `list assignment index out of range`. That is because you can't extend a list simply by assigning elements that aren't there. If you want to add new values to the end of a list, use `append`: `list_of_leap_years.append(given_year)`.
3. The function returns `list_of_leap_years` but doesn't define it. The function should start by creating it as an empty list.

Fixing these problems, the function will look like this:

```
def find_leap_years(given_year):
    list_of_leap_years = []
    count=0
    while count < 15:
        if given_year % 4 == 0:
            if given_year % 100 != 0 or given_year % 400 == 0:
                list_of_leap_years.append(given_year)
                count += 1
        given_year += 1
    return list_of_leap_years
```

I've taken out the list index `i` because you don't need it to keep track of how many elements the leap year list has. If you need to discover it, use `len(list_of_leap_years)`.

Comment: thanks mate..defining the list as an empty list at the start of the function did it for me..much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`list_of_leap_years` is not declared inside a function, so it takes value from outer scope, which might be undefined, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Is your aim something like this? Your question and code are not as clear as to what you are trying to achieve but if this was your goal I can explain what I think is going wrong in your code.

```
def find_leap_years(given_year):
    list_of_leap_years = []
    for i in range(given_year + 1): 
        if i%4 == 0:
            if i%100 == 0:
                if i%400 == 0:
                    list_of_leap_years.append(i)
                else:
                    continue
            else:
                list_of_leap_years.append(i)
        else:
            continue
    return list_of_leap_years

leap_years = find_leap_years(2000)
print(leap_years)
```

**Output**

```
(xenial)vash@localhost:~/python$ python3.7 leapyear.py 
[0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 36, 40, 44, 48, 52, 56, 60, 64, 68, 72,   
76, 80, 84, 88, 92, 96, 104, 108, 112, 116, 120, 124, 128, 132, 136, 140,    
144, 148, 152, 156, 160, 164, 168, 172, 176, 180, 184, 188, 192, 196, 204, 
208, 212, 216, 220, 224, 228, 232, 236, 240, 244, 248, 252, 256, 260, 264, 
268, 272, 276, 280, 284, 288, 292, 296, 304, 308, 312, 316, 320, 324, 328, 
332, 336, 340, 344, 348, 352, 356, 360, 364, 368, 372, 376, 380, 384, 388, 
392, 396, 400, 404, 408, 412, 416, 420, 424, 428, 432, 436, 440, 444, 448, 
452, 456, 460, 464, 468, 472, 476, 480, 484, 488, 492, 496, 504, 508, 512, 
516, 520, 524, 528, 532, 536, 540, 544, 548, 552, 556, 560, 564, 568, 572, 
576, 580, 584, 588, 592, 596, 604, 608, 612, 616, 620, 624, 628, 632, 636, 
640, 644, 648, 652, 656, 660, 664, 668, 672, 676, 680, 684, 688, 692, 696, 
704, 708, 712, 716, 720, 724, 728, 732, 736, 740, 744, 748, 752, 756, 760, 
764, 768, 772, 776, 780, 784, 788, 792, 796, 800, 804, 808, 812, 816, 820, 
824, 828, 832, 836, 840, 844, 848, 852, 856, 860, 864, 868, 872, 876, 880, 
884, 888, 892, 896, 904, 908, 912, 916, 920, 924, 928, 932, 936, 940, 944, 
948, 952, 956, 960, 964, 968, 972, 976, 980, 984, 988, 992, 996, 1004, 1008, 
1012, 1016, 1020, 1024, 1028, 1032, 1036, 1040, 1044, 1048, 1052, 1056, 1060, 
1064, 1068, 1072, 1076, 1080, 1084, 1088, 1092, 1096, 1104, 1108, 1112, 1116, 
1120, 1124, 1128, 1132, 1136, 1140, 1144, 1148, 1152, 1156, 1160, 1164, 1168, 
1172, 1176, 1180, 1184, 1188, 1192, 1196, 1200, 1204, 1208, 1212, 1216, 1220, 
1224, 1228, 1232, 1236, 1240, 1244, 1248, 1252, 1256, 1260, 1264, 1268, 1272, 
1276, 1280, 1284, 1288, 1292, 1296, 1304, 1308, 1312, 1316, 1320, 1324, 1328, 
1332, 1336, 1340, 1344, 1348, 1352, 1356, 1360, 1364, 1368, 1372, 1376, 1380, 
1384, 1388, 1392, 1396, 1404, 1408, 1412, 1416, 1420, 1424, 1428, 1432, 1436, 
1440, 1444, 1448, 1452, 1456, 1460, 1464, 1468, 1472, 1476, 1480, 1484, 1488, 
1492, 1496, 1504, 1508, 1512, 1516, 1520, 1524, 1528, 1532, 1536, 1540, 1544, 
1548, 1552, 1556, 1560, 1564, 1568, 1572, 1576, 1580, 1584, 1588, 1592, 1596, 
1600, 1604, 1608, 1612, 1616, 1620, 1624, 1628, 1632, 1636, 1640, 1644, 1648, 
1652, 1656, 1660, 1664, 1668, 1672, 1676, 1680, 1684, 1688, 1692, 1696, 1704, 
1708, 1712, 1716, 1720, 1724, 1728, 1732, 1736, 1740, 1744, 1748, 1752, 1756, 
1760, 1764, 1768, 1772, 1776, 1780, 1784, 1788, 1792, 1796, 1804, 1808, 1812, 
1816, 1820, 1824, 1828, 1832, 1836, 1840, 1844, 1848, 1852, 1856, 1860, 1864, 
1868, 1872, 1876, 1880, 1884, 1888, 1892, 1896, 1904, 1908, 1912, 1916, 1920, 
1924, 1928, 1932, 1936, 1940, 1944, 1948, 1952, 1956, 1960, 1964, 1968, 1972, 
1976, 1980, 1984, 1988, 1992, 1996, 2000]
```

Comment: can't we use : leap_years=find_leap_years(2000) ?

Comment: Try to see it like this, `leap_years` is a empty list, when we run `find_leap_years` its going through every number and then `appending` that number to `leap_years`.  This the issue I think you ran into with your code, you were setting `leap_years = find_leap_years(2000)` right and your function was returning a value, but if your function returns say `1992` okay what happens is `leap_years = 1992` now when its returns `1996`, `leap_years = 1996` you are just reassigning `leap_years` over and over to a different value

Comment: We can use `leap_years = find_leap_years(2000)` I'll show you but the format of the solution will change slightly

Comment: Okay take a look now, see we can do `leap_years = find_leap_years(200)` but we want to make sure then that our function is returning a completed list not one variable at a time, so now what happens is our function creates a complete list of all the leap years and then we use `leap_years = find_leap_years(2000)` and since our function returns a list , `leap_years` now represents that list.